# ModbusMaster.h - changing node

Tags: arduino-uno, modbus

I'm using the ModbusMaster.h library on a project, with arduino-uno and a TTL/RS-485 converter, and the function has to identify the slave that it is communicating. The slaves goes from 1 to 16. After I've begun the connection,

```
ModbusMaster node(1);
node.begin(9600);
```

I have to send a message, and if this massage returns an error, I have to change the slave number, until I got an valid answer. But I didn't find any functions to close this connection, or to delete it, I even have tried,

```
delete &node;
```

but it didn't work. I'm trying to close this connection so I could begin another one with another node, because I didn't find a function to change the slave number.

Comment: I see no function to change the `_u8MBSlave` other that the [constructor](https://github.com/4-20ma/ModbusMaster/blob/master/ModbusMaster.cpp#L66). My C isn't great by you might try something like `node = ModbusMaster(2);`

Comment: Generally speaking, you should never call `delete` on something unless you originally created it with `new`. Attempting to delete an object from the stack could cause your program to crash or misbehave in other ways.

Comment: Indeed that would not work. But why not `ModbusMaster* node = new ModbusMaster(id)`, then send, check for error, if so `delete *node`, `++id`, repeat? Not the most efficient, but simple. (You could also add a function to change the id to the library.)

Comment: Gerben, it didn't work, =/. Thanks for the tip Peter. Fuenfundachtzig, how do you pronunciate that? O.o, but it didn't work either. But to solve, I had to create a function that keep creating another nodes, and every time it made a new node, it'll send a request, and if the request was an error, it passes to create another node, if the answer was a success, it would made: `ModbusMaster node4(4)` "if the success was on the 4th try", then: `node4.begin(); node = node4;`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this question is too old and the API has changed, so my answer is reference.

The ModbusMaster constructor does not accept parameters.

From reading the source code, the method `begin(uint8_t slave, Stream &serial)` just initializes variables and can be called again with a new `slave` value without the need to destroy the ModbusMaster object.

Reference:

[1] https://github.com/4-20ma/ModbusMaster/blob/master/src/ModbusMaster.cpp, line 61.